# How can I optimize this? (find Taxicab number)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, netbeans, integer-arithmetic

I wrote a small program to find the first 5 Taxicab numbers (so far only 6 are known) by checking each integer from 2 to 5E+15. The definition of Taxicab numbers is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number).

However, my program took 8 minutes just to reach 3E+7. Since Taxicab(3) is in the order of 8E+7, I hesitate to let it run any further without optimizing it first.

I'm using NetBeans 8 on Ubuntu 16.10 on a HP 8560w, i7 2600qm quad core, 16GB RAM. However, Java only uses 1 core, to a maximum of 25% total CPU power, even when given Very High Priority. How do I fix this?

```
public class Ramanujan 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    long limit;
    //limit = 20;
    limit = 500000000000000000L;
    int order = 1;

    for (long testCase = 2; testCase < limit; testCase++) 
    {
        if (isTaxicab(testCase, order)) 
        {
            System.out.printf("Taxicab(%d) = %d*****************************\n", 
                order, testCase);
            order++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (testCase%0x186a0 ==0) //Prints very 100000 iterations to track progress
            {
                //To track progress
                System.out.printf("%d \n", testCase);   
            }

        }
    }
}


public static boolean isTaxicab(long testCase, int order)
{
    int way = 0; //Number of ways that testCase can be expressed as sum of 2 cube numbers.
    long i = 1;
    long iUpperBound = (long) (1+Math.cbrt(testCase/2));
    //If testCase = i*i*i + j*j*j AND i<=j 
    //then i*i*i cant be > testCase/2
    //No need to test beyond that
    while (i < iUpperBound) 
    {
        if ( isSumOfTwoCubes(testCase, i) ) 
        {
            way++;
        }   
        i++;
    }
    return (way >= order);
}


public static boolean isSumOfTwoCubes(long testCase,long i)
{
    boolean isSum = false;
    long jLowerBound = (long) Math.cbrt(testCase -i*i*i);

    for (long j = jLowerBound; j < jLowerBound+2; j++) 
    {
        long sumCubes = i*i*i + j*j*j; 
        if (sumCubes == testCase)
        {
            isSum = true;
            break;
        }
    }


    return isSum;
}
}
```

Comment: You're only using one thread so it's not going to use more than one CPU. To use multiple CPU's, you need to divide up the work over multiple threads. Since each `isTaxicab` test is independent of each other, that shouldn't be too hard. Have each thread search over a different part of the `testCase` space - let each thread handle a large block of numbers and have a central function to hand out the next block of numbers - make sure that the central function is properly synchronized.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sorry that I phrased that so ambiguously. NetBeans 8.2 actually allowed me to use more than 1 core now, but only up to 40% of total CPU power. In any case, I've only started Introduction to CS last week, and have no idea how to divide the process to multiple cores.

Comment: You also don't want to print every single number to the console.

Comment: @JacobG. Yeah that makes sense. Maybe I should print only once every 10000 iterations or so.

Comment: @JacobG. I added a line so that the program prints only `if (testCase % 100000 == 0)`. NetBeans then gave me options to convert the constant to Hexadecimal, Octal or Binary. Which option would be the fastest?

Comment: Neither, they're equivalent lol

Answer (score 0):

The program itself will only ever use one core until you parallelize it.

You need to learn how to use Threads.

Your problem is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). Parallelizing too much (i.e. creating too many threads) will be detrimental because each thread creates an overhead, so you need to be careful regarding exactly how you parallelize.

If it was up to me, I would initialize a list of worker threads where each thread effectively performs `isTaxicab()` and simply assign a single `testCase` to each worker as it becomes available.

You would want to code such that you can easily experiment with the number of workers.